# A quadrilateral ABCD with an incribed circle with center on side of D. Prove AD + DC > AB + BC

Tags: geometry

for a tangential quadrilateral ABCD, where the center of the inscribed circle lies on the same half plane of AC as the vertex D, is there a way to prove that

$$AD + DC > AB + BC$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Since the center O lies on the same half plane as D, ∠AOC < 180. Given that AO and CO are angle bisectors of ∠POQ and ROS, respectively, ∠POS > ∠QOR. Then, with radius $r$

$$DP = DS = r\tan \frac{∠POS}{2} >  r\tan \frac{∠QOR }{2} = QB = BR $$
$$\implies DP + DS > QB +  BR$$Therefore,

$$AD + DC = DP + DS + PA + SC > QB + BR + QA + RC = AB + BC $$

where  PA = QA and SC = RC are used.